# How to prevent user from using fake gps in Flutter Web (PWA)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, mock-location

I build a Flutter Web project, but I would like to know, is there a package that can handle user to prevent from using fake gps or mock location? for Android and iOS, there is package called `trust_fall` and `trust_location` to detect mock location.. how about package for Flutter Web? is there an available package for Flutter Web to detect mock location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trust_fall` depends on detecting jailbroken or SafetyNet failure, which isn't available for a webpage while `trust_location` credits [LocationAssistant](https://github.com/klaasnotfound/LocationAssistant) for the algorithm it use, which [rely](https://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/05/27/location-on-android-stop-mocking-me/) on `Location.isFromMockProvider()` that also unavailable for a webpage. You can use IP geolocation, but that's fraught with false positives from VPN use, and at most only accurate up to a city level.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your answer... I am trying this package ```https://pub.dev/packages/ipfinder``` and hope will get the things that I want